# Once I use multiple classes it expects an indented block

Tags: python

I have multiple classes inside a single file. Once I try to run the code it says it expects an indented block. The error always occurs with the second class in reading order, even if I switch the order of the classes. I am sure that my indents are correct.

So I expect that you can't have multiple separate classes inside one file? So how can I define a class inside a different file and then use it inside the main file?

```
class FirstClass:
     def __init__():

class SecondClass: 
     def __init__():
```

Comment: Empty methods are not allowed. `def __init__():` is empty. That's an error

Comment: Also that's not how Python does comments. Have you considered learning the language basics before trying to write a program in it?

Comment: Also it looks like your code is indented 5 rather than 4 spaces. And you have `_init__` instead of `__init__`.

Comment: Anytime you have a : , contents are expected. Use **pass** if you have to, for a placeholder.   Plus, you forgot **self**.  I kindly suggest doing the python intro or "dive into python" first.  This is way too trivial to post here.

Comment: 5-space indentation is an unconventional choice, but not an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the *method* or leave it empty by specifying `pass`

```
class FirstClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class SecondClass:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed empty classes aren't allowed.

Comment: Yes bu you can also use the pass keyword. I've edit my post